# Problema com history back java script

Tags: javascript

Tenho uma pagina, chamada pagina_1.php de cadastro que ao clicar em um botão confirmar ele me leva para a pagina_2.php, que realiza todas as operaçoes no banco, só que no final da pagina tem um código assim:

```
echo "<script language='javascript'>
    history.back();
</script>";
```

Ai da um problema de requisição da seguinte forma:

Confirmar reenvio do formulário

Comment: Eu quero que simplesmente volte para a pagina anterior, só isso. tenho mais informações sobre o erro, aparece isso: ERR_CACHE_MISS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quando você utiliza o `history.back()` o comportamento é similar a clicar no botão de retornar do browser, por isso que ele pede que você confirme o reenvio do formulário.

Se você quiser voltar para a página1 que você estava antes, você pode gerenciar o URL desta forma

```
echo "<script language='javascript'>
    window.location.href = 'URL da página anterior';
</script>";
```

Se sua página anterior é dinâmica, você precisa tratar para qual será a página de retorno com uma lógica. Utilizar o history back **não é uma boa prática**

Comment: Obrigado, não sabia que erá má pratica usar o history back, trabalho com outras linguagens alem de o javascript então as vezes deixo escapar umas coisinhas assim.